# Are there browsers for windows or linux that still using actual webkit engine version not blink engine?

Tags: webkit, blink

Is there any browser for windows or linux that still using actual webkit engine version not blink engine?

Answer (score 1):

This is a question that I also ask, periodically, so I can give an updated reply:

- for Linux, there are several more-or-less platform-specific browsers that use `webkit2-gtk` (a more-or-less up-to-date WebKit2 implementation): notably Web/Epiphany and Midori. Both are rather simple/lightweight browsers.
- for MS Windows, there is still the more full-fledged Maxthon 5 browser (or virus, according to some), but I have been unable to determine what WebKit version it really uses (based on its user agent string it might NOT be WebKit2). Some quick testing suggests it's a good alternative for slower hardware (many hybrid tablet PCs!) as WebKit is noticeably less resource-hungry than WebEngine (aka Chromium aka Blink). Note however that Maxthon 6 will become just another blink on the block (unless they decide to keep the dual-engine feature).
- for Linux AND MS Windows (Qt-based, cross platform) there are Konqueror and Otter-Browser. The former is mostly focussed on its QtWebEngine backend, but the latter is indeed focussed on the "rebooted" QtWebKit (and aims to reimplement Opera 12; it provides installers for MS Windows).

The QtWebKit reboot is largely a 1-person effort at the moment that could probably stand a few more contributors, notably to merge a more recent WebKit version.

Answer (score 0):

according to wikipedia, maxthon browser still uses webkit (You can switch engines in Maxthon though)

> As of version 3, Maxthon supports two web browser engines: WebKit and
> Trident
>
> Wikipedia